# Find out which tool is using GTK2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, gtk

Almost all X-tools are GTK+ or QT based. Is there any simple way to find out, which X-tools I've installed in my system are still using GTK2, i.e., it is relying on GTK2 themes?

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 17.04 Zesty, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
apt-cache rdepends --installed libgtk2.0-0
```

to see the installed packages depending on the Gtk libs.

Comment: Hold on, that list all of them, not just my installed packages, right? -- I've found many of those I don't have are listed as well.

Comment: @xpt it should show only the installed ones (not only dependencies but also recommends and conflicts). Maybe try the installed flag after the rdepemds. There is also a apt-rdepemd tool which might be a bit better to use.

Comment: Yep! the `--installed` flag does the trick. thx!